# Using mySQL/Wordpress to get data from a metadata column

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am using wordpress metadata to store dynamic data.
I've ran into a wall and need some help,I have once piece of meta data that basically is a multidimensional array.
The issue I have is how the metadata is stored I'm having a hard time retrieving what i need.

At the bottom I have included how wordpress stores the data (it's one column)
This is how the first entry looks like before it's stored

```
   shopper_wp_id:3

   shopper_status_time:2011-11-29 17:24:49

   shopper_status_comment:COMMENTS

   shopper_status:declined

   shopper_answers:["TEST1","TEST2","TEST3","TEST4","TEST5","TEST6"]

   shopper_preapproval_status:maybe
```

What i need to be able to do is find all the entries where the shopper_wp_id = 3 and the shopper_status = declined

If those 2 values where next to each other but they are separated by a datetime that is ever changing. Any ideas?

```
a:4:{i:0;a:6:{s:13:"shopper_wp_id";s:1:"3";s:19:"shopper_status_time";s:19:"2011-11-29 17:24:49";s:22:"shopper_status_comment";s:8:"COMMENTS";s:14:"shopper_status";s:8:"declined";s:15:"shopper_answers";a:6:{i:0;s:5:"TEST1";i:1;s:5:"TEST2";i:2;s:5:"TEST3";i:3;s:5:"TEST4";i:4;s:5:"TEST5";i:5;s:5:"TEST6";}s:26:"shopper_preapproval_status";s:5:"maybe";}i:1;a:7:{s:13:"shopper_wp_id";s:4:"2063";s:19:"shopper_status_time";s:19:"2011-11-30 16:37:52";s:22:"shopper_status_comment";s:17:"sgdfsgfgdfdfgfhsh";s:14:"shopper_status";s:4:"paid";s:15:"shopper_answers";a:6:{i:0;s:10:"sdfsadfdfs";i:1;s:11:"dfgdsfgsdfg";i:2;s:10:"sdfgfdsfdg";i:3;s:9:"dgsdfgdfg";i:4;s:10:"sgdfsgfdgd";i:5;s:10:"sdfgfgfgds";}s:26:"shopper_preapproval_status";s:3:"yes";s:13:"blog_post_url";s:17:"http://google.com";}i:2;a:6:{s:13:"shopper_wp_id";s:4:"2916";s:19:"shopper_status_time";s:19:"2011-11-29 20:13:13";s:22:"shopper_status_comment";s:7:"dfbdfdf";s:14:"shopper_status";s:8:"declined";s:15:"shopper_answers";a:6:{i:0;s:15:"cvczxvzxcvzxcbz";i:1;s:11:"zcvfxzbxbxb";i:2;s:8:"zvzxcbzb";i:3;s:10:"zfdbfdbdfb";i:4;s:11:"zdfbdfbfbdf";i:5;s:6:"bfdfdh";}s:26:"shopper_preapproval_status";s:2:"no";}i:3;a:6:{s:13:"shopper_wp_id";s:4:"1614";s:19:"shopper_status_time";s:19:"2011-11-29 20:16:06";s:22:"shopper_status_comment";s:15:"sfdhfsdhsdfhdsh";s:14:"shopper_status";s:8:"declined";s:15:"shopper_answers";a:6:{i:0;s:8:"sdfsdfsd";i:1;s:15:"zvzfbdfbsdfbdbd";i:2;s:15:"dfgdsfhsfdsfhdf";i:3;s:17:"xfbfghfghnfsgnfgn";i:4;s:17:"dsfgshfdshsfdghsg";i:5;s:12:"sdffsdhsdfhh";}s:26:"shopper_preapproval_status";s:2:"no";}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The string is serialized, so you need to unserialize it, then you can more easily get the information you need using the resulting structure (in this case, an associative array). For example

```
$data = 'a:4:{i:0;a:6:{s:13:"shopper_wp_id";s:1:"3";s:19:"shopper_status_time";s:19:"2011-11-29 17:24:49";s:22:"shopper_status_comment";s:8:"COMMENTS";s:14:"shopper_status";s:8:"declined";s:15:"shopper_answers";a:6:{i:0;s:5:"TEST1";i:1;s:5:"TEST2";i:2;s:5:"TEST3";i:3;s:5:"TEST4";i:4;s:5:"TEST5";i:5;s:5:"TEST6";}s:26:"shopper_preapproval_status";s:5:"maybe";}i:1;a:7:{s:13:"shopper_wp_id";s:4:"2063";s:19:"shopper_status_time";s:19:"2011-11-30 16:37:52";s:22:"shopper_status_comment";s:17:"sgdfsgfgdfdfgfhsh";s:14:"shopper_status";s:4:"paid";s:15:"shopper_answers";a:6:{i:0;s:10:"sdfsadfdfs";i:1;s:11:"dfgdsfgsdfg";i:2;s:10:"sdfgfdsfdg";i:3;s:9:"dgsdfgdfg";i:4;s:10:"sgdfsgfdgd";i:5;s:10:"sdfgfgfgds";}s:26:"shopper_preapproval_status";s:3:"yes";s:13:"blog_post_url";s:17:"http://google.com";}i:2;a:6:{s:13:"shopper_wp_id";s:4:"2916";s:19:"shopper_status_time";s:19:"2011-11-29 20:13:13";s:22:"shopper_status_comment";s:7:"dfbdfdf";s:14:"shopper_status";s:8:"declined";s:15:"shopper_answers";a:6:{i:0;s:15:"cvczxvzxcvzxcbz";i:1;s:11:"zcvfxzbxbxb";i:2;s:8:"zvzxcbzb";i:3;s:10:"zfdbfdbdfb";i:4;s:11:"zdfbdfbfbdf";i:5;s:6:"bfdfdh";}s:26:"shopper_preapproval_status";s:2:"no";}i:3;a:6:{s:13:"shopper_wp_id";s:4:"1614";s:19:"shopper_status_time";s:19:"2011-11-29 20:16:06";s:22:"shopper_status_comment";s:15:"sfdhfsdhsdfhdsh";s:14:"shopper_status";s:8:"declined";s:15:"shopper_answers";a:6:{i:0;s:8:"sdfsdfsd";i:1;s:15:"zvzfbdfbsdfbdbd";i:2;s:15:"dfgdsfhsfdsfhdf";i:3;s:17:"xfbfghfghnfsgnfgn";i:4;s:17:"dsfgshfdshsfdghsg";i:5;s:12:"sdffsdhsdfhh";}s:26:"shopper_preapproval_status";s:2:"no";}}';
$data = unserialize($data);
foreach ($data as $shopper){
    if(isset($shopper['shopper_wp_id']) && $shopper['shopper_wp_id'] == 3){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Justin... I was trying to accomplish it in mysql due to the amount of rows it could be and also the amount of shoppers that could be in any row... I think I have the answer and will post it as soon as it's tested... I'm using the mySQL Locate function with a having clause...  will post back

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone but i figured it out, not sure it's the best but it seems to be pretty quick..
I ended up using a combination of mySQL's LOCATE and SUBSTRING with a HAVING kicker.
Below is my function and then below that is the SQL that it creates.

```
function db_get_users_shops_by_shopper_status($shopper_wp_id, $limit = 0, $shopper_status) {
    global $wpdb;
    if (!is_array($shopper_status)) {
        $shopper_status = array($shopper_status);
    }
    $sql = "
    SELECT wp_posts . *,
        SUBSTRING(meta_value, 
          LOCATE('{s:13:\"shopper_wp_id\";s:" . strlen($shopper_wp_id) . ":\"" . $shopper_wp_id . "\";', meta_value), 
          LOCATE('s:15:\"shopper_answers\";', meta_value))
        AS shopper_entity
    FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta 
    WHERE post_type='shoppertunity' 
        AND wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND meta_key = 'shoppers'
        AND meta_value LIKE '%s:13:\"shopper_wp_id\";s:" . strlen($shopper_wp_id) . ":\"" . $shopper_wp_id . "\";%'
    HAVING shopper_entity LIKE ";
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($shopper_status); ++$i) {
        if ($i > 0) {
            $sql .= " OR shopper_entity LIKE ";
        }
        $sql .= " '%s:14:\"shopper_status\";s:" . strlen($shopper_status[$i]) . ":\"" . $shopper_status[$i] . "\";%'";
    }

    if ($limit != 0) {
     $sql .= "LIMIT " . $limit;
     }
    //echo($sql ."<br/><br/>");
    $results = $wpdb -> get_results($sql);

    return $results;
}
```

SQL Results

```
SELECT 
`wp_posts`.*,
SUBSTRING(`meta_value`,
  LOCATE('{s:13:"shopper_wp_id";s:4:"2063";',
          `meta_value`),
  LOCATE('s:15:"shopper_answers";', `meta_value`)) AS `shopper_entity`
```

FROM
  `wp_posts`,
  `wp_postmeta`
WHERE
   `post_type` = 'shoppertunity' AND `wp_posts`.`ID` = `wp_postmeta`.`post_id` AND `meta_key` = 'shoppers' AND `meta_value` LIKE '%s:13:"shopper_wp_id";s:1:"3";%'
HAVING `shopper_entity` LIKE '%s:14:"shopper_status";s:9:"completed";%' OR `shopper_entity` LIKE '%s:14:"shopper_status";s:4:"paid";%'